# Flink Kafka Consumer - change number of retries on timeout exception

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I have a Flink job that consumes data from Kafka Using Flink's KafkaSource ("Flink-connector-Kafka" library).

Once in a while I get a Timeout Exception "Failed to get metadata for all topics" (We are investigating Kafka issues and network issues). But, I can see in the Exception log that the request to Kafka had only 1 attempt.

Is it possible to increase the number of attempts to more than 1 ?
And if so, how?

Exception log:

```
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.coordination.OperatorCoordinatorHolder$LazyInitializedCoordinatorContext.failJob(OperatorCoordinatorHolder.java:600)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.coordination.RecreateOnResetOperatorCoordinator$QuiesceableContext.failJob(RecreateOnResetOperatorCoordinator.java:237)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.source.coordinator.SourceCoordinatorContext.failJob(SourceCoordinatorContext.java:374)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.source.coordinator.SourceCoordinatorContext.handleUncaughtExceptionFromAsyncCall(SourceCoordinatorContext.java:387)
    at org.apache.flink.util.ThrowableCatchingRunnable.run(ThrowableCatchingRunnable.java:42)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkRuntimeException: Failed to list subscribed topic partitions due to 
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.KafkaSourceEnumerator.checkPartitionChanges(KafkaSourceEnumerator.java:234)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.source.coordinator.ExecutorNotifier.lambda$null$4(ExecutorNotifier.java:133)
    at org.apache.flink.util.ThrowableCatchingRunnable.run(ThrowableCatchingRunnable.java:40)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get metadata for all topics.
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.subscriber.KafkaSubscriberUtils.getAllTopicMetadata(KafkaSubscriberUtils.java:37)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.subscriber.TopicPatternSubscriber.getSubscribedTopicPartitions(TopicPatternSubscriber.java:48)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.KafkaSourceEnumerator.getSubscribedTopicPartitions(KafkaSourceEnumerator.java:219)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.source.coordinator.ExecutorNotifier.lambda$notifyReadyAsync$5(ExecutorNotifier.java:130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=listTopics, deadlineMs=1703430983336, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=1703430983497) timed out at 1703430983397 after 1 attempt(s)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:165)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.subscriber.KafkaSubscriberUtils.getAllTopicMetadata(KafkaSubscriberUtils.java:34)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=listTopics, deadlineMs=1703430983336, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=1703430983497) timed out at 1703430983397 after 1 attempt(s)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException: Cancelled listTopics request with correlation id 66857 due to node 1001 being disconnected
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's any way to do that directly.

But you can configure a [restart strategy](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/ops/state/task_failure_recovery/#restart-strategies) so that the error doesn't cause a terminal job failure. You'll also need to have checkpointing in place for this to be effective.

Comment: Thanks for the answer David, 
We already have checkpointing with a predefined strategies:
  "restart-strategy":                                     "fixed-delay",
  "restart-strategy.fixed-delay.attempts":                60,
  "restart-strategy.fixed-delay.delay":                   "10 s"

But these configurations are not what I seek. I don't want to have restarts to my app because of connection issues to Kafka, it causes duplications in data. I would expect a way to configure few attempts to kafka before restarting the Flink job.

Thank you for the willing to help !

Comment: You won't end up with duplicates if you can set things up correctly (though there is some risk if you can't set the transaction timeout to be large enough). See https://github.com/confluentinc/flink-cookbook/tree/master/kafka-exactly-once